# Trying to preview my app release in Google Play Console and keep getting error

Tags: android, google-play-console

This is my first time attempting to publish a mobile app to the Google Play store. I paid for the ability to use the Google Play Console for publishing purposes. I have followed the tutorials, signed and built the release version (opted in for the android app bundle to try and make the process as easy as possible), and uploaded the .aab file in the correct place while creating a new release. During all this, there were no errors indicated in the console regarding the release. I filled out all the fields, clicked 'Save', and then clicked 'Review Release'. Upon clicking that last button, I received an error: 'An unexpected error has occurred. Please try again. (5A35450E)'.

I have searched numerous places looking for a solution to no avail.

I am using Google Chrome as my web browser.

Has anyone else ran into this issue? If you did, how did you solve it?

Comment: It is new to me that one would have to pay for using the console. So far there's 5 different error codes: [query](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-play-console%5D+%22An+unexpected+error+has+occurred.+Please+try+again%22).

Comment: I didn't have a developer account until yesterday. They require a one time $25 payment to acquire one.

Answer (score 0):

It may Sound Dumb but I managed to fix it for myself and I don't know if this is solution but do as i say and i hope it will fix it, and it only worked this way

- Get into the Draft Release page
- Press on Review Release and wait for the error
- Disable Anti-Virus (In My case is Avast Free)
- Return to Chrome and you will get SSL Error.
- Press F5, and you should see the new page
- Press roll-out release

Note: If u disable Avast before getting the error, it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what my problem was.

Since I had selected US as a deployment region, it is required to have a privacy policy. I am not collecting any data from people, so I didn't create a privacy policy initially since the console stated I didn't need one. Once I added a privacy policy, it allowed me to continue with the release.